# Transform picture box image to a mat object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-c++

I am trying to process an image obtained via Windows form application or GUI using opencv libraries. But I don't know how to get the picture box image to a mat object. The following code will put things in perspective.

```
  PictureBox->Load(TextBox->Text);

  cv::Mat mImage;

  mImage = PictureBox->Image;  //Ofcourse, it is not right. But this is my intention.
```

I tried one more way.

```
  mImage = imread(TextBox->Text); //Yes, there is a type difference (System::String and std::string)
```

I also tried static_cast. But still, not working. Is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: `#include<msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>`, then `imread(msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(TextBox->Text));`

Comment: That worked. Thank you for taking your time to answer.

Comment: Sgarizvi you should add this as an answer